# rely on the result of a query to run another nodejs mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm

Hey guys I have the following node code and it works fine

```
import express from 'express';
import connection from '../index.js'
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/allTemplates', function (req, res) {

    let queryString="select count(*) as exist from users where userName='bob'";
    let query = connection.query(queryString, (error, result) => {
        if(error) {throw error;}
        res.json(result);
    })
});
module.exports = router;
```

what I want to do is react to this with something like

```
if(exists==1){error='sorry but that user already exists';} else {
queryString="insert into users (userName, email, address) values('bob', 'emailAddress@email.com', 'address')";
let query = connection.query(queryString, (error, result) => {
            if(error) {throw error;}
            res.json(result);
        })
}
```

I come from a php background so this is all very new and the async of node freaks me out but I have to use it for my new job. How would I react to a result of one query and run another one based on the outcome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I put the mysql library in a variable called database and I am using async await to run queries. In the database file I connect to the database and set up my variables like so:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const util = require("util");

const awsConfig = {
  host: process.env.RDS_HOST,
  user: process.env.RDS_USER,
  password: process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.RDS_DATABASE
};

const connection = mysql.createConnection(awsConfig);

connection.query = util.promisify(connection.query.bind(connection));
connection.end = util.promisify(connection.end.bind(connection));

module.exports = connection;
```

Than i use async await to run queries and use the results to run or not run others. like so:

```
let result;
let sqlStatement ="";

    result = await database.query(sqlStatement);
    let userExists = result[0].exist;
 sqlStatement =
    "SELECT COUNT(*) AS exist FROM user where userName=" +
    database.escape(req.body.userName);
if(userExists==0){
    result = await database.query("INSERT INTO user SET ?", [req.body]);
}
```

hope this helps someone else